# Regex to accept all type of files except one (NIFI)

Tags: regex

What will be the regular expression to accept all type of file formats except zip format?

```
.*
```

accepts all types of files. But I don't want zip files. So what will be regex in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use a negative lookahead to ensure your input doesn't end with `.zip` for which you can use this regex,

```
^(?!.*\.zip$).+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8FUu8/1/)

Here `^` and `$` match start and end of line and `(?!.*\.zip$)` negative lookahead ensures it doesn't match a text ending with `.zip` and `.+` matches any character one or more.